# Making a certain kind of table in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make a table that is two columns. The one of the left will have many rows and a scroll bar. The one on the right will be a big box that I'll have buttons in that will change when you click on a different block on the left. Is this even possible?

Comment: Honestly I've looked the places I know of and ran into a wall. Was all simple how to make the Column and rows but never apply this sort to it. So I knew to ask the question on stack overflow for some assistance. Let alone if it was possible to do it.

Comment: This sounds like it is possible, yes.  However you need to add more details to your question.  Ideally you would attempt it and then post when you get stuck, detailing the issue you got stuck on.

Comment: Okay, this is my first time using stack so I apologize for my inexperience with posting. I've made the boxs the way I wanted to but I don't know how to apply the scrolling and the different templates to be created when I click on a different box on the left. Any links to somewhere I can read how to do it would be appreciated(mainly what I was looking for) or any explanation of how it could be done.

Comment: Edit your question and put in the code that you have done already for this. When you add code to your question it must be preceded by an empty line and each line of code must start with at least 4 spaces.

Comment: I think you want is called a master-detail view.

Answer (score 1):

Offcourse this is possible, almost everything is possible. I made some assumptions; the box on the right is some sort of detailed view of the record on the left? Ans because the question is tagged as javascript it should be a ajax call or something.

It is not so much if this is possible in Rails, on the back-end it would be a simple model with a number of records. On the left you'll have a list something like; Item.all.select( :id, :name ) which could be available from /items.

On the right the route /items/{id} should be defined to retrieve one item Item.find_by_id( {id} ). If you want it to be responsive you can respond with json so that you can parse it to html using javascript. Backwards compatibility would be that if you'll go to /items/{id} with your browser the detailed version should already be loaded.

I suggest you'll take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. Ruby only does the back-end, it serves pages. It does nothing with styling or responsive design.

For the styling and scrolling on the left side of the page, I suggest you'll use a list or just div's, a table is not very easy to style I'm not sure what you're styling skills are. But it has nothing to do with Ruby or Rails. Perhaps you can use bootstrap or some other html/css framework.

For the responsiveness you can use JQuery.get. For the basic idea, I suggest looking into http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp, it is far from perfect but it will give you the idea.